# Trouble with duplicate Google + pages and YouTube account

Tags: youtube, google-plus

I'm having trouble with Google + linked to my YouTube account. I originally did not want a Google + page and held out until YouTube forced me to do so.

The first time this happened I took the time to work on the page and got some followers etc. Later I was having difficulty working on my YouTube account and 'temporarily' disconnected my Google + page. When I reconnected it, it created a new Google + page with the same name. I disconnected again and ended up with 3 duplicate pages.

I've heard things about user's entire Google accounts getting deleted and I'm very concerned as my YouTube account is the result of many years of daily hard work and promotion. It's become a full time job on top of everything else I do. I'm very concerned. Does anyone know how to link a particular Google + page to YouTube and to remove extra ones without risking deleting a YouTube account?

Answer (score 1):

It now is safe to delete any Google+ thing without deleting your channel. In fact, Google+ unintegration is nearly done now, new channels can't even have Google+ connected to them anymore.